# Перевод строчки `Complete sign up`

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, регистрация

Переведите, пожалуйста, строчку `Complete sign up`:

> [image: скриншот строки без перевода]

Не переведено как минимум с середины июля, то есть уже почти три месяца.

(что намекает нам на то, что процесс перевода устроен не так идеально, как мог бы...)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Перевод сайта обеспечивается силами самих участников, а упомянутая Вами кнопка появляется, когда процесс регистрации затягивается. Понятно, что для зарегистрированных или анонимных участников она не появляется вовсе. А если не видно проблем, то и перевод обычно затягивается.

В любом случае, теперь перевод добавлен, но в силу отсутствия обновления движка сайта на выходных, появится не раньше понедельника.

Comment: Спасибо, а можете, пожалуйста, пояснить вот это: `А если не видно проблем, то и перевод обычно затягивается`. Разве нету какого-нибудь списка всех строк для перевода, который обычно пустой, а при изменении английских строк этот список становится не пустым и тогда участники его переводят? Спасибо

Comment: @user269040 список можно посмотреть на transifex (если есть доступ), но: там много лишнего, что реально ещё не используется, т.е. пока нет смысла переводить, чего-то нет потому что оно подгружается из других мест или по причине ошибок локализации. Поэтому сразу непонятно чему там в первую очередь стоит уделить внимание и внимание уделяется согласно репортам на Мете или в чате.

Comment: Спасибо, а можете пояснить, пожалуйста, насчёт `там много лишнего, что реально ещё не используется`, там именно много строк, которые будут когда-то потом использоваться, или много строк, которые вряд ли будут когда-либо использоваться?

Comment: И ещё вопрос (если можно): так всегда было, что в этом списке много строк?

Comment: @user269040 например, там есть строки, относящиеся к [документации](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/3240681), которую уже прикрыли. Есть строки по Jobs (вакансии), которых у нас нет, и планов на них тоже в неанглийских сообществах нет, насколько я знаю. Может что-то ещё попадается. Сейчас в transifex [около 10тыс строк, из которых 2тыс не переведены](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgdYt.png). Строки появляются, изменяются, чем больше функционала, тем больше строк.

Comment: судя по всему, локализаторам нужна возможность запускать движок в тестовом окружении, чтобы отловить все такие случаи и для разный ролей

Comment: @mymedia тестировщиками выступаем мы с вами. А "локализаторы"—разработчики просто обрамляют английскую строку в функцию. На этом их локализация заканчивается. Но иногда и обрамлять забывают.