# Перевод причины достижения лимита по заданию вопросов

Tags: дефект, локализация

Если задать несколько плохих вопросов (или один очень плохой), то при повторной попытке задать вопрос (то есть при переходе на страницу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) будет показано предупреждение о достижении лимита по вопросам. Оно практически всё на английском. Было бы очень здорово его перевести.

> [image: скриншот страницы «Вы достигли лимита по вопросам»]

Спасибо.

Comment: Насчет последнего предложения — Я Вам уже [отвечал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5975/176217) о том, как работает система перевода. Если хотите помочь с переводом, а не только лишь с поиском ошибок, то можете ознакомиться с [этим вопросом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/176217).

Comment: А нет никакой системы перевода. Есть добровольцы, которые в свободное время идут и переводят.

Comment: @alexolut, да, извините, действительно как-то некрасиво получается, я только и делаю что прошу кого-нибудь переводить

Comment: @alexolut, а разве вы не единолично ответственный за Transifex? А то складывалось именно такое впечатление.

Comment: @Arhad нет. Просто я несколько более активен в последнее время, чем другие участники. Но начиналось всё ещё без меня. Посмотрите сообщения по метке [meta-tag:локализация], думаю, должно быть понятно.

Comment: @Arhad нет, там еще Николас, Влад и я - редакторы. Но у меня хватает сил только на модерацию. Вроде как в основном alexolut тащит локализацию в последний год.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не стоит забывать ещё о [куче народа на transifex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ogQN.png). Забавно видеть кривизну перевода в системе для перевода :-D.

Comment: Завёл [FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301810/339911) по данной ситуации на MSE, т.к. в текущем виде переводить текст совсем не комильфо. Голосуйте, ставьте лайк, подписывайтесь ... авось сделают лаконичнее.

Comment: @alexolut сапожники без сапог, ага. Кстати, я тут повникал глубже в тему переводов и инструментов для них (называются они CAT – computer assisted translation tool). Так вот, транзифекс там не очень-то котируется. Например, он не предоставляет контекст — а разные другие «кошки» умеют показывать оригинал и собирать переведённые документы. А ещё в нем вроде как нет проверки орфографии.

Comment: @alexolut цитирую: "It has been a while since I've used it, but at the time it even lacked basic spellchecking. Their position was "but you can install a spellchecker in your browser". That might be technically true but 1) you don't want your translators all using different spellcheckers and 2) it shows they clearly haven't thought about the translator's needs at all."

Comment: @alexolut "The spellchecker is a very minor thing, but to me it was really indicative of their mindset. Skilled, experienced translators want to work with their own tools. They don't want to be forced into a platform created by people that don't even understand how they work."

Comment: @alexolut а сейчас этот текст переведён?

Comment: @alexolut и вообще, есть возможность такие страницы просматривать от лица такого юзера? Ну, типо как в fb/vk можно посмотреть страницу от лица друга/гостя и т.п.

Comment: @Suvitruf только если сокпупета завести. Хотя у разрабов, я думаю, механизмы должны быть более удобные для подтверждения баг-репортов.

Comment: Так как восстановиться после такого бана? Stranger in the Q, СКАЗАЛ МНЕ, ЧТО ПРОСТО НУЖНО ПОДОЖДАТЬ, если это так то просто напишите мне!!! (в чате или сюда)... очень хочется задавать вопросы и получать ответы. Я задавал хорошие вопросы и получал балы и даже сам отвечал...

Comment: как я найду удаленные сообщения чтобы поправить их рейтинг?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts на странице [своих удалённых вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/230420).

Comment: @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik♦ можно ли поднять тревогу, после того как отредактировал сообщение с отрицательным рейтингом (там даже конкурс есть) так, чтобы тебе сняли "минусы" (у меня их рейтинг "минус 5")самим, его высочество, модератором?Помогите плиз!

Comment: @ArthurAlunts модераторы не могут минусы отменять.